# Still getting an IllegalStateException when using Google's People API despite subscribing on another thread using RxJava

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin, rx-java

Note: I'm using Kotlin along with RxKotlin for the useful extension functions.

I'm trying to get some user data using Google's People API, and I just migrated all my AsyncTasks and stuff to using RxJava. Everything is working except for this part:

```
private fun getGooglePerson(service: PeopleService?, account: GoogleSignInAccount) =
    Single.just(service?.people()
                    ?.get("people/me")
                    ?.setPersonFields("emailAddresses,birthdays,genders,phoneNumbers")
                    ?.execute() ?: Person()) // If null, return an empty person (shouldn't ever be null, though)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeBy(
                    onError = {/*Do something*/},
                    onSuccess = {/*Do something*/}
            )
```

Specifically, I'm getting an `IllegalStateException` with the message, `Calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock`. I'm confused because I was under the impression that calling `subscribeOn` should shift everything both above and below it (unless an `observeOn` follows it) to another thread (in this case, `Schedulers.io()`) I tried rewriting the code like so:

```
private fun getGooglePerson(service: PeopleService?, account: GoogleSignInAccount) =
    service?.people()
                    ?.get("people/me")
                    ?.setPersonFields("emailAddresses,birthdays,genders,phoneNumbers")
                    ?.execute() ?: Person() // If null, return an empty person (shouldn't ever be null, though)
            .toSingle()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeBy(
                    onError = {/*Do something*/},
                    onSuccess = {/*Do something*/}
            )
```

Still, no dice. I'm completely stumped; what should I do? Where should I put that call to `execute()` so that it runs on a different thread? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break this down a little.

```
Single.just(service?.people()
                    ?.get("people/me")
                    ?.setPersonFields("emailAddresses,birthdays,genders,phoneNumbers")
                    ?.execute() ?: Person())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

We're starting with a `Single.just(someValue)`. We could rewrite your code like so, and it would be technically identical to what you wrote:

```
val person = service?.people()
                    ?.get("people/me")
                    ?.setPersonFields("emailAddresses,birthdays,genders,phoneNumbers")
                    ?.execute() ?: Person())
Single.just(person)
```

Do you see the problem? The service call is executed first in order to provide a value to the `Single.just` call.

In order to run your service call once the rest of the chain has been setup (ie, upon subscription), you can use [`defer`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Single.html#defer(java.util.concurrent.Callable)):

```
Single.defer(() -> service?.people()
                    ?.get("people/me")
                    ?.setPersonFields("emailAddresses,birthdays,genders,phoneNumbers")
                    ?.execute() ?: Person())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

(syntax may be off, I don't have an IDE handy)

Comment: This solved it! Yes, the syntax in the end was off; I had to write it as `Single.defer { Single.just(...) }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` and so on. For anyone coming to this question in the future, though, I'd just like to add that I'm going with `Single.fromCallable { service?.people() ... }.subscribeOn(...) ...` instead, because it avoids the nested call and still accomplishes the same effect. Thanks!

([`fromCallable` doc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#fromCallable-java.util.concurrent.Callable-))